# bandwagonhost space not free after I delete big file

Tags: linux, putty

I have a VPS on bandwagonhost.com, today it control panel show my space almost full,

[image]

then I log in to VPS using putty and find /var/log/asterisk/messages it too big, so I stop asterisk and delete this file.

after that, when I run df command, it shows space is success freed,

[image]

but when I open bandwagonhost's control panel, it still shows space almost full, does not change anything.

Does anybody know why it happens? Will it affect my using of bandwagonhost?

Comment: It probably doesn’t update in real-time.

Comment: maybe , let me monitor it when tmr